# Symfony 3.1 - How to set data for form entity type

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony, symfony-forms, formbuilder

I have a form class that i need to populate inside a form event (FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA).

For text type is very simple:

```
$form->get("fieldName")->setData("stringValue");
```

For entity type this doesn't work:

```
$form->get("fieldName")->setData(array("val1", "val2", "val3"));
```

I think that i have to first instantiate the entities and after set the data in this way:

```
$entity1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBundle:MyEntity")->find("val1");
$entity2 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBundle:MyEntity")->find("val2");
$entity3 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AcmeBundle:MyEntity")->find("val3");
$form->get("fieldName")->setData(array($entity1, $entity2, $entity3));
```

In this way it works, but i have to inject EntityManager inside the FormEventSubscriber and i need to know first the entityType.

1) Is that the right way?

2) How i can retrive the type of the entity form the FormBuilder Class?

*I can retrive the entity type in this way:*

```
$form->get ( "fieldName" )->getConfig()->getAttributes()['data_collector/passed_options']['class']
```

Thanks in advance

Hi @dragoste, thanks for your reply. My goal is to populate (server side), with previous value, the form fields before show it. I think using form events is the best way to accomplish my goal (i'm using FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA event), but i have problem when i want to populate this kind of field:

```
...
    $builder->add("manyToManyField", EntityType::class, array (
            "class" => "AcmeBundle:TestEntity",
            "choice_label" => "id",
            "multiple" => true 
    ))
```

in EventSubscriber class i have to do somethings like:

```
    public function onFormSetDataPre(FormEvent $event){
          $form = $event->getForm();
          $field= $form->get("manyToManyField");
          $field->setData($prevValue);
}
```

My problem is that in EventSubscriber $prevValue is the ID of the entity. If i set directly the ID it doesn't work. In setData() i have to pass the entity, to pass entity i have to fetch it from database.
My question are:

1) Is right fetch it from database)

2) Is right the way i obtain the entity repository?

```
$field->getConfig()->getAttributes()['data_collector/passed_options']['class']
```

Comment: You're doing something weird here and it's hard to guess what (or actually why) are you doing. But for sure @1 No. I'm pretty sure it's wrong. Anyway, it would be easier to give you proper solution if you provide code for broader context (and explain it). This should include entities (input data), form (issue subject) and the target situation (output data) .

Comment: @dragoste i have added some info. I want to say you, that i have solved the problem, but i don't know if is the right way

Comment: But why aren't you passing data while creating the form? Also where do values `"val1", "val2", "val3"` come from. Are they constant?

Comment: @dragoste  
When i close the modal with inside the form, i serialize the form and save the serialized string in session. val1 val2 val3 are the id of the selected element. In event subscriber i get this value from the session.